# Error when set an ImageAdapter in Inflate Layout?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a gridview on LayoutInflater, when i test my app, it always crashes.
here is my code :

```
public class Level1 extends Fragment {
public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
Level1 f = new Level1();    
return f;
}   
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null);  
GridView gridView = (GridView) root.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(root.getContext()));
}
```

I think, my problem is in "setAdapter". I can't use context "xxx.this". I've try to change setAdapter context with "getContext" and "getApplicationContext" but it still crashes.
when i delete "setAdapter" my app working but without gridView.

My ImageAdapter is look like this :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
        R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4,
        R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6,
        R.drawable.pic_7, R.drawable.pic_8,
        R.drawable.pic_9, R.drawable.pic_10,
        R.drawable.pic_11, R.drawable.pic_12,
        R.drawable.pic_13, R.drawable.pic_14,
        R.drawable.pic_15
};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return imageView;
}

    }
```

Please help me..

Comment: post the stack trace. try using `getActivity()` to get the context of the hosting activity.

Comment: what is the stack trace?

Comment: Do we really have getActivity(); defined in BaseAdapter?

Comment: post the whole onCreateView . DOes R.layout.grid_layout contain R.id.grid_view?

Comment: StackTrace is the detailed error message of the error which causes the crash printed via logcat. You can either see it in eclipse (press Windows -> Show View -> Android -> Logcat) or open a command shell (on Windows press Start -> Run -> Enter "cmd") and call adb logcat.

Comment: maybe the gridView is null at that point. Try to check if it exists under that id in your XML layout file.

Comment: in logcat i found error message this :
FATAL EXCEPTIOn : main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 0):

Please set a breakpoint on this line `GridView gridView = (GridView) root.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);` and start debugging your app (in eclipse it's the button on the left side of the button you usually use to start your application). When the breakpoint is reached please step over one step and see if gridView is null. For me this looks like the most reasonable source of your error. But without a detailled error message it's hard to say, so please update your post.

Comment: in logcat i found error message this : FATAL EXCEPTIOn : main java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting OUTOFMEMORY exception its generally because you are using large size images. you will have to sample it down. and in fragment you have to use `getactivity()` for context.

Comment: try using using smaller images for a check. if that really is your error then post a comment.i can help you with it.

Comment: i use images from a project source gridview example. I just want to modificate it on layoutInflater, but always get crashes when i put a "new ImageAdapter()".

On that sample project , gridView working perfect. and now I want to put the gridView on LayoutInflater.

Comment: then try using getactivity() for context i.e use  gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

Comment: I've tried using getContext(), getContext(), getApplicationContext(), but still crashes. if anything to do with the grid layout or  ImageAdapter?

Comment: but i still think it is bcoz of the image size...just try using smaller images once...use the default launcher icon and try...

Comment: getcontext() wont work in fragment.you have to use getactivity(),but that is not the root of the error bcoz it doesnt have anything to do with out of memory exception...

Comment: Thank you. it's working now, i use getActivity(). Theres no problem with images size.

Comment: good to know.if it helped you could accept the answer and end the question.:)